# How to fix misaligned html divs when printing with jquery using flex css

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have a div content to print.

I create a media query to screen and to print.

The media query to print is very similar to screen media query.

When showing in the screen, all is ok, but when I try to print the divs becomes misaligned.

Fidlde: https://jsfiddle.net/20dhfoub/7/

What am I doing wrong?

//markup

```
<div id="folha">
        <div class="container-print center">
            <div class="color-black">
                MY TEST
            </div>
            <div class="paciente color-black">
                <div><strong class="ng-binding">THATIANA NUNES ALMEIDA</strong></div>
                <div class="medplano">
                 <div class="ng-binding">Sem Pref</div>
                 <div class="ng-binding">IRB-APOSENTADOS/EX COLABORADORES</div>
                </div>
                <div class="medplano">
                  <div class="ng-binding">15/01/182018 20:46:13</div>
                  <div>TOTEM</div>
                  <div class="ng-binding">Matr:00000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-black">
                <span style="border-radius:50%; border:solid black 1px;padding:5px">TRAN</span>
                <span style="border-radius:50%; border:solid black 1px;padding:5px">REC</span>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="container-obs color-black">
          <div class="ng-binding"></div>      
          <div class="ng-binding">Rx e Procedimentos no receituário com CID. Fratura podemos cobrar  Consulta.Recepção: Fratura podemos cobrar Consulta.Densitometria óssea com autorização via fax 2240.1621.Procedimentos acima 300 chs, necessita de autorização. Paciente deverá apresentar lâmina de pagamento. Observar sempre validade da carteira.
          </div>      
        </div>    
 </div>
```

//css

```
 @media screen {
    #printSection{
        display: none;
    }
   .circle{
     border-radius:50%; 
     border:solid black 1px;
     padding:5px
    }
    .container-obs{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container-print {
         display: flex;
         padding-top:10px;
    }
    .container-print div:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .center {
     align-items: center;
    }
    .medplano{
         display: flex;
    }
    .medplano>div{
         margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .paciente {
         margin-left: 15px; 
    }
 }
 @media print {
    body * {
      display:none;
    }
    #folha{
      display:none;
    }
   .circle{
    border-radius:50%; 
    border:solid black 1px;
    padding:5px
   }
    #printSection, #printSection * {
        display: block!important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        printer-colors: exact;
        color-adjust: exact;
    }
    @page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
    .container-obs{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container-print {
         display: flex;
         padding-top:10px;
    }
    .container-print div:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .center {
     align-items: center;
    }
    .medplano{
         display: flex;
    }
    .medplano>div{
         margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .paciente {
         margin-left: 15px; 
    }
 }
```

//js

```
$(function() {
 var PrintDoc=function(id) {
        var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
        // if there is no printing section, create one
        if (!printSection) {
            printSection = document.createElement('div');
            printSection.id = 'printSection';
            document.body.appendChild(printSection);
        }
        var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elemToPrint) {
                    printElement(elemToPrint);
        }
        function printElement(elem) {
            // clones the element you want to print
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            printSection.innerHTML = '';
            printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            console.log(printSection.innerHTML)
            window.print();
        }
        if (window.matchMedia) {
                var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
                mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
                    if (!mql.matches) {
                        afterPrint();
                    } else {
                        // before print (currently does nothing)
                    }
                });
            }

        window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
        function afterPrint() {
            // clean the print section before adding new content
               printSection.innerHTML = '';

        }
};
PrintDoc('folha');

});
```

Comment: Well `#printSection, #printSection * { display: block!important;` looks kinda suspicious in that regard.

Comment: I guess that you need to print cloned document, not original?

Comment: I just need to print div id=#folha, I just cloned when I was trying solve the problem. No need of clonning. But It doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple fix for you. only thing that I added was css declaration to hide direct child `body > folha` elemenet

```
 @media print {

    body > #folha{
      display:none;
    }
 }
```

```js
$(function() {
  var PrintDoc = function(id) {
    var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
    // if there is no printing section, create one
    if (!printSection) {
      printSection = document.createElement('div');
      printSection.id = 'printSection';
      document.body.appendChild(printSection);
    }
    var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elemToPrint) {
      printElement(elemToPrint);
    }

    function printElement(elem) {
      // clones the element you want to print
      var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
      printSection.innerHTML = '';
      printSection.appendChild(domClone);
      // console.log(printSection.innerHTML)
      window.print();
    }
    if (window.matchMedia) {
      var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
      mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (!mql.matches) {
          afterPrint();
        } else {
          // before print (currently does nothing)
        }
      });
    }

    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

    function afterPrint() {
      // clean the print section before adding new content
      printSection.innerHTML = '';
    }
  };
  PrintDoc('folha');

});
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
    display: none;
  }
  .container-obs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 5px
  }
  .container-print {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .container-print div:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .center {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .medplano {
    display: flex;
  }
  .medplano>div {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  .paciente {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

@media print {
  body>#folha {
    display: none;
  }
  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0mm;
  }
  .container-obs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container-print {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .container-print div:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .center {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .medplano {
    display: flex;
  }
  .medplano>div {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  .paciente {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="folha">
  <div class="container-print center">
    <div class="color-black">
      MY TEST
    </div>
    <div class="paciente color-black">
      <div><strong class="ng-binding">THATIANA NUNES ALMEIDA</strong></div>
      <div class="medplano">
        <div class="ng-binding">Sem Pref</div>
        <div class="ng-binding">IRB-APOSENTADOS/EX COLABORADORES</div>
      </div>
      <div class="medplano">
        <div class="ng-binding">15/01/182018 20:46:13</div>
        <div>TOTEM</div>
        <div class="ng-binding">Matr:00000</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="color-black">
      <span class="circle">TRAN</span>
      <span class="circle">REC</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-obs color-black">
    <div class="ng-binding"></div>
    <div class="ng-binding">Rx e Procedimentos no receituário com CID. Fratura podemos cobrar Consulta.Recepção: Fratura podemos cobrar Consulta.Densitometria óssea com autorização via fax 2240.1621.Procedimentos acima 300 chs, necessita de autorização. Paciente deverá apresentar
      lâmina de pagamento. Observar sempre validade da carteira.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is jsfiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/20dhfoub/18/

Comment: Thank you, My problem is almost solved. In the real case, I have many other div above 'diiv id=#folha' and  diiv id='#folha' is  child of other divs. Here is the filddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Lcwd9vav/1/ based in your correction. Is there a way to hide all body content in media print except the specific div id=#folha?

Comment: in this case where you have cloned element on page it's hard (you can do it if replace element id or class).. if you are doing cloining only for printing needs then just remove javascript and cloning and in media print only do this: `#folha{ display: block !importatn }`

Comment: I did into https://jsfiddle.net/2171h6uw/  . I hide all the body first in media print and show div id #folha. But it doesnt work. Can you check this fiddle, please? I get rid off the clonning as well

Comment: With this fiddle the print dialog preview results empty.